# Media Foundation : mpeg4 stream from camera gets distorted when GOV length is greater than 1

Tags: rtsp, ms-media-foundation

I am using Media Foundation on client side to display live mpeg4 stream from AXIS Camera through RTSP server.

Client side video works very fine if i set GOV @ camera = 1, i.e. camera will only send I-Frames. But if GOV is increased and camera starts sending P-Frames also, my video suddenly gets distorted at regular intervals. I cannot set GOV = 1 for always because it consumes a lot of bandwidth.

Following is the code for RequestSample method where i supply Samples to Media Foundation :

```
RTPFrame frame = null;
byte[] frameBytes = null;

frame = _VideoJitter.GetNextFrame();
frameBytes = frame.GetFrameAsBytes();
frame.FrameType= RTPFrame.PredictFrameType(frameBytes);

_videoEncapsulatedSample.ReadSampleFrom(frameBytes);
videoSample = _videoEncapsulatedSample.MfSample;

long timestamp = nextSampleTimestamp ?? 0;   

videoSample.SetSampleTime(timestamp);
duration_video = (long)GetPresentationTime(frame);

videoSample.SetSampleDuration(duration_video);
nextSampleTimestamp = timestamp + duration_video;

if (frame.FrameType == FrameType.IFrame)
{
videoSample.SetUINT32(MFAttributesClsid.MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, 1);
}

return videoSample;
```

Do i need to set any attribute for processing P-Frames??

Any help would be highly appreciated....

**Update (2012/02/22) :**

I ran some statistics and found that some times I-frames never reach client, i.e. suppose GOV = 15, so every 15th frame should be an I-Frame, but sometimes (at irregular intervals) client receives an I-Frame after 28 or 30 or 59  P-frames.

Any pointers ??

Thanks,

Prateek